# PyQt5 - Adding widget to layout dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a custom widget where the user can dynamically add more [some other] custom widget onto the window. Here is my attempt:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class LoadModelWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoadModelWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # ------------------------ GUI Components ------------------------ #
        self.setFixedHeight(100)
        self._container = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self)
        self._container.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding))
        self._container.setFixedHeight(100)
        self._container.setFixedWidth(210)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self._model_to_select_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Selected model")
        layout.addWidget(self._model_to_select_label, 0, 0)
        self._model_to_select_list = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self._model_to_select_list, 0, 1)
        _slice_method_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Slice method")
        layout.addWidget(_slice_method_label, 1, 0)
        self._list_of_slicing_method = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self._list_of_slicing_method, 1, 1)

        self._bottom_radius_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Bottom radius")
        layout.addWidget(self._bottom_radius_label, 2, 0)
        self._bottom_radius_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self._bottom_radius_edit, 2, 1)
        self._top_radius_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Top radius")
        layout.addWidget(self._top_radius_label, 3, 0)
        self._top_radius_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self._top_radius_edit, 3, 1)
        self._height_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Height")
        layout.addWidget(self._height_label, 4, 0)
        self._height_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self._height_edit, 4, 1)

        self._x_dir_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("X direction")
        layout.addWidget(self._x_dir_label, 5, 0)
        self._x_dir_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self._x_dir_edit, 5, 1)
        self._y_dir_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Y direction")
        layout.addWidget(self._y_dir_label, 6, 0)
        self._y_dir_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self._y_dir_edit, 6, 1)
        self._z_dir_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Z direction")
        layout.addWidget(self._z_dir_label, 7, 0)
        self._z_dir_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self._z_dir_edit, 7, 1)

        self._remove_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Remove model")
        layout.addWidget(self._remove_btn, 8, 0)

        self._bottom_radius_label.setVisible(False)
        self._bottom_radius_edit.setVisible(False)
        self._top_radius_label.setVisible(False)
        self._top_radius_edit.setVisible(False)
        self._height_label.setVisible(False)
        self._height_edit.setVisible(False)
        self._x_dir_label.setVisible(False)
        self._x_dir_edit.setVisible(False)
        self._y_dir_label.setVisible(False)
        self._y_dir_edit.setVisible(False)
        self._z_dir_label.setVisible(False)
        self._z_dir_edit.setVisible(False)

        self._container.setLayout(layout)

        # -------------------- Other attributes -------------------- "
        self._filename = ""

        # -------------------- Assign slot and signal -------------------- "
        self._list_of_slicing_method.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.slice_method_changed)
        self._remove_btn.clicked.connect(self.remove_model)

    def set_model_dir(self, filename, filedir, suggested_slicing_method="Parallel"):
        # Assign only the name of the file, not the whole stl model
        self._filename = filename
        self._filedir = filedir

        self._list_of_slicing_method.addItem("Parallel")
        self._list_of_slicing_method.addItem("Revolution")
        self._list_of_slicing_method.addItem("Radial")
        self._list_of_slicing_method.addItem("ParallelCurve")

        self._list_of_slicing_method.setCurrentText(suggested_slicing_method)

    def get_model_full_dir(self):
        return self._filedir + "\\" + self._filename

    def remove_model(self):
        self._filename = ""
        self._filedir = ""
        self._list_of_slicing_method.clear()

    def slice_method_changed(self):
        is_parallel = self._list_of_slicing_method.currentText() == "Parallel"
        is_radial = self._list_of_slicing_method.currentText() == "Radial"

        self._bottom_radius_label.setVisible(is_radial)
        self._bottom_radius_edit.setVisible(is_radial)
        self._top_radius_label.setVisible(is_radial)
        self._top_radius_edit.setVisible(is_radial)
        self._height_label.setVisible(is_radial)
        self._height_edit.setVisible(is_radial)

        self._x_dir_label.setVisible(is_parallel)
        self._x_dir_edit.setVisible(is_parallel)
        self._y_dir_label.setVisible(is_parallel)
        self._y_dir_edit.setVisible(is_parallel)
        self._z_dir_label.setVisible(is_parallel)
        self._z_dir_edit.setVisible(is_parallel)

        padding = 50
        minimum_height = 100
        new_height = (self._bottom_radius_label.height() + padding)*is_radial + (self._top_radius_edit.height() + padding)*is_radial + (self._height_label.height() + padding)*is_radial + (self._x_dir_label.height() + padding)*is_parallel + (self._y_dir_label.height() + padding)*is_parallel + (self._z_dir_label.height() + padding)*is_parallel
        if (new_height > minimum_height):
            self._container.setFixedHeight(new_height)
            self.setFixedHeight(new_height)
        else:
            self._container.setFixedHeight(minimum_height)
            self.setFixedHeight(minimum_height)

class LoadModelColumn(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoadModelColumn, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # ------------------------ GUI Components ------------------------ #
        self._layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self._add_model_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add model(s)")
        self._layout.addWidget(self._add_model_btn, 0, 0)
        self._clear_all_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Clear all")
        self._layout.addWidget(self._clear_all_btn, 0, 1)

        self._all_load_model_widgets = []

        self.verticalSpacer = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        self._layout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer)

        self._load_model_group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        self._load_model_group.setLayout(self._layout)

        self._scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)
        self._scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self._scroll_area.setFixedHeight(600)
        self._scroll_area.setFixedWidth(250)
        self._scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self._scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self._scroll_area.setWidget(self._load_model_group)

        # -------------------- Assign slot and signal -------------------- "
        self._clear_all_btn.clicked.connect(self._clear_all_models)
        self._add_model_btn.clicked.connect(self._add_models)

    def _clear_all_models(self):
        for widget in self._all_load_model_widgets:
            self._layout.removeWidget(widget)
            widget.deleteLater()

        self._all_load_model_widgets = []

    def _add_models(self):
        widget = LoadModelWidget()
        widget.set_model_dir("hi", "hello")
        self._all_load_model_widgets.append(widget)
        self._layout.addWidget(widget, len(self._all_load_model_widgets), 0, 1, 0)
```

Currently, when a widget is added, for some reason, it will try to occupy all the scroll area. But obviously, I don't really want that since I would like it to be allocated to the necessary space only.

Here's an example of what it is doing right now when the user press Add Model(s) button:
[image]

But this is what I would like it to be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding widgets to a top level window widget, but you're not setting a layout for them.

The simple answer for your issue is to correctly set the layout for the widgets you're creating. Add the following at the bottom of `LoadModelWidget`'s `__init__`:

```
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self._container)
```

and this at the bottom the `__init__` of `LoadModelColumn`:

```
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self._scroll_area)
```

Then remove all unnecessary `setFixedHeight`, which don't make any sense.

I strongly suggest you to better study how [layout manager work](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), since all widgets that require adjusting their contents also require that you set a layout for them.
Then I also suggest you to better clarify the object structure of your classes. For example, there's no need to subclass `LoadModelWidget` from QWidget, if it will always contain a single group box: just subclass QGroupBox.

<sub>As a side note (but, still, very important), always try to keep your examples as minimal as possible (read more about creating [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (you might even end up finding the solution on your own); also, and that's also very important, always make efforts to make those examples *immediately reproducible*: from your code, it was **not** clear what class was used as the parent), and your example is very long; we *must* be able to copy and paste your code and run it with as little efforts as possible: this means that we *want* to help you, but you have to help us to help you.</sub>

Comment: Harsh, but very true. Thanks for the tip with QGroupBox, really open my eye with that. I'm new to front end development so I'm still learning things. However, when I add the layout to the bottom of init as you suggested, I still cannot get what I wanted. It almost like I'm missing a spacer (which I think I already include by self._layout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer)). Any thoughts?

Comment: On that note, I think I did add a layout for both of my class (although I might not add it correctly). With LoadModelWidget, I add the layout to the QGroupBox (_containter). With LoadModelColumn, I also add the layout to the QGroupBox (_load_model_group), which then be contained inside the scroll area. The scroll area simply make the QGroupBox scrollable, if I understand correctly, so there's no need for a layout.

Comment: If you need a "spacer" to ensure that the previous widget(s) use only the minimal required size, you can use `addStretch()`, just be careful to always use `insertWidget(index, widget)` with an index equal to `layout.count() - 1`. About the second comment: as already said, adding a parent QWidget with a single child widget and no layout manager set for the parent will just make things unnecessarily complicated; just subclass QGroupBox (with a layout correctly set) and add its instances instead: the layout will automatically ensure that the contents are correctly resized.

Comment: To clarify: you did *not* set a layout for those classes: you have set layouts for the children. This means that the parent widgets will know *nothing* about the children contents; yes, you've set fixed heights on those parents, but that doesn't work very well in most cases (like yours, in fact: most widget size *hints* are actually computed only as soon as they're actually shown, and *not* in the `__init__`). Layout managers are useful for those purposes too: they ensure that widgets are correctly resized in any case, even *after* their initialization *and* that of their children.

Comment: Thanks for clearing out some of the confusion I had! Currently I'm using Grid Layout and I don't think I can use addStretch for that. Is there anything similar?

Comment: @AnhTran you're already using one: QSpacerItem; add another one at the bottom of the layout with the vertical policy set to expanding, and always ensure you insert widgets at an index count - 1. Another possibility is that you don't use a grid layout, but nested layouts: a vbox as main container, which contains an hbox for the buttons and another vbox that will be used to contain the new widgets, then you add a stretch at the end of the "main" vbox layout. In this way, you just need to keep a reference to the internal vbox and add new widgets to that.